# Lynx stops downloading file b/c no space is left on device

Tags: lynx

I'm working on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and I want to download a file using Lynx. The file I want is downloaded from web-site that I have to authenticate on - which is why I decided to use lynx. Which happens to work for files of a size lower than approx. 1 GB. But the file I would like to download is about 8 GB. Here's what I do:

I switch onto a mounted EBS disk which happens to provide 47GB of free space:

```
ubuntu@ip-...:~/data$ df -h                                                                                                 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/xvdf        50G   52M   47G   1% /home/ubuntu/data
```

The owner is my working account:

```
ubuntu@ip-...:~$ ls -la 
total 22608
...
drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Apr 17 13:37 data
...
```

My current working directory is the root folder of that disk:

```
ubuntu@ip-...:~/data$ echo $PWD
/home/ubuntu/data
```

So, I fire up lynx, authenticate on the web-site and initiate the download - which seems to work fine - as I can follow the progress. But as soon as Lynx hits about more or less 1 GB of downloaded data I get an error message and lynx crashes:

```
Alert!: HTFWriter_write: FileWriter: No space left on device
```

Any ideas how to resolve or further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Not an answer but you could try to work around this behaviour by using `curl` instead of `lynx`. Curl also does authentication, and can resume downloads.

Comment: Is it downloading to `/tmp` before moving to the final destination?

Comment: @muru: no leftovers in /tmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the folder where Lynx would store temporarily the downloaded file was located on the main disk somewhere - which happens to be significantly smaller.

The solution is to set `LYNX_TEMP_SPACE` to a folder on a larger disk.

```
export LYNX_TEMP_SPACE=~/data/tmp
```